# Read error codes without scanner on Pontiac G6

Tags: obd-ii, cel

I've read certain vehicles may begin flashing their check engine light if one bridges the diagnostic plug correctly with some wire before starting the vehicle. How does one do this for a Pontiac G6? I've attached a diagram.

[image: obd2 plug]

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I'm assuming you're trying to read error codes without a scan tool.  You might want to clarify the question and the title.

Comment: i just find the comments on OBD interesting considering my 99 Plymouth Neon would flash the engine light like hell when ever it tripped a code. ive never owned a scan tool. partly because im broke (which could potentially be partl;y because i dont own a scanner) and because of this reason i too was looking to see if you could flash codes on the 10 g6 lol.

Comment: Mike H, if you're near AutoZone or other big box auto stores with free OBD II checks, call and ask first before visiting. AutoZone provides free OBD II decoding from stored error codes in vehicles as long as the check engine indicator remains on. Reading error codes takes less than a minute to plug into the OBD II port, turn on ignition and display codes.

Answer (score 4):

As [this article](http://www.hotrod.com/how-to/interior-electrical/1404-how-to-read-diagnostic-trouble-codes-breaking-the-code/) points out, the ability to blink codes was available with older OBD-I vehicles.  Once the OBD-II standard hit, the ability to "blink" out codes was lost.  This changeover to ODB-II happened in 1996 for vehicles sold in the US.

I know the same is true for Volkswagen cars.  Early models had the ability to blink out the codes when something was jumped, but modern cars needed a special reader.

This bit is conjecture on my part, but I think the reason is that OBD-II is much more complex so the simple blinking was just abandoned.

Comment: You are right for the most part, but I understand (haven't seen personally) there are some cars with OBD-II which you can blink the codes from ... GM is not one of them ... neither is Ford/Chrysler ... nor any other brand you'd normally find in the US for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

pontiac g6 is easy no tools needed or obd! turn key from off to on twice on second time leave in on position. car will ding the codes! like ding, d,d , d pause d,d,d,d,d,d,. thats four dings pause then 6.. code 46 anti theft system key no recongnizd. 44 is o2 censor ect..